# Why doesn't this c++ code template work? I'm having trouble

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int list[10];
    int a,b,c;
    int d=1;
    int e=0;
    printf("Enter a starting number to find 10 prime numbers: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter a ending number to find 10 prime numbers: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    for(c=0;c<10;c++)
    {
        while(a<b)
        {
            while(d<a)
            {
                if(a%d==0)
                {
                    e=1;
                }
                d++;
            }
            a++;
        }
        if(e==0)
        {
            list[c]=a;
            printf("%d is prime.",list[c]);
        }
    }
}
```

The code that will add 10 prime numbers in the given range to the list arr and print them. Why doesn't it work? Thanks. Please explain.

Comment: You are incrementing `c` regardless of whether `d` _is_ prime or _not_. So, `c` is _not_ the number of _primes_, just the count of numbers you test for primality. So, try: remove `c++` from the `for`. Then, after the `printf` do: `c++;` So, then, `c` _will_ be the count of the number of primes found.

Comment: also this is nether c++ nor a template

Answer (score 0):

to flesh out @Craig answer

```
   for(c=0;c<10;)
    {
        while(a<b)
        {
            while(d<a)
            {
                if(a%d==0)
                {
                    e=1;
                }
                d++;
            }
            a++;
        }
        if(e==0)
        {
            list[c]=a;
            printf("%d is prime.",list[c]);
            c++;
        }
    }
```